# How To Select Item In Sitecore Content Editor

Tags: sitecore

I've got a Sheer UI wizard that collects information from a user and then creates a content item in sitecore. The wizard is launched using an command template.

I'd like the wizard to make the newly created content item the currently selected item in the content editor but I can't work out how to do this. Does anyone know how this is done?

**Update**

Trayek's advice has got me a bit further. I've now got the following code in the Command I use to launch the wizard:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyNewContentCommand : Command
{

    public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
    {
        ClientPipelineArgs args = new ClientPipelineArgs();
        args.Parameters["id"] = context.Parameters["id"];
        Context.ClientPage.Start(this, "Run", args);
    }

    protected void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
    {
        if (!args.IsPostBack)
        {
            // This runs when the users clicks to add the item
            // in the content editor. 

            // Launches a modal wizard to collect user data

            string id = args.Parameters["id"];

            string controlUrl = Sitecore.UIUtil.GetUri("control:MyNewItemWizard");
            UrlString urlStr = new UrlString(controlUrl);
            urlStr.Append("id", id);

            SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(urlStr.ToString(), true);
            args.WaitForPostBack();

        }
        else if (args.HasResult)
        {
            // This runs once the wizard has finished

            // Wizard passes ID of created item in its result
            // This is used to find the newly created item.
            Item created = Client.GetItemNotNull(ID.Parse(args.Result));

            // Sending these messages result in refreshing the child items
            // of the parent. And they work.
            Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, string.Format("item:updated(id={0})", created.Parent.ID));
            Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, string.Format("item:refreshchildren(id={0})", created.Parent.ID));

            // This message should select the new item in content editor, but
            // it doesn't have the desired effect.
            Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, string.Format("item:load(id={0})", (object)created.ID));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question. The problem is caused because there appears to be a race condition between the "Refresh Items In Content Tree" command and "Select Item In Content Tree" command. I have to delay the select command for a few milliseconds to get it to work.

```
Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, 
    string.Format("item:updated(id={0})", created.Parent.ID));
Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, 
    string.Format("item:refreshchildren(id={0})", created.Parent.ID));
Context.ClientPage.ClientResponse.Timer(
    string.Format("item:load(id={0})", created.ID), 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a read through [this](http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/open-content-editor-on-specific-item.html) link. It gives you 3 options:

- Generate a URL and link to it
- Open it from XAML application
- Open it from JavaScript

Comment: Thanks your tip got me a bit further: the content tree is now updated to show the new item, but I still can't get content editor to select my new item. Any ideas?

Comment: Sitecore uses Context.ClientPage.SendMessage(this, "item:loadid=" + args.Result + ")");
Did you give that a try? 

I'm wondering why are you casting the created.ID to object? Wouldn't created.ID or created.ID.ToString() work?

Comment: The send message code was based on decompiling some existing sitecore commands; this is where the object cast came from. See my answer for the cause of the problem.